# Symfony2 run bin/vendors git error

Tags: symfony, vendors

I downloaded the latest symfony2 (2.0.10) and tried to run bin/vendors install but it prints the following:

> Installing/Updating symfony
>   Cloning into /Users/i/sf2_proj/vendor/symfony...
>   error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation timed out while accessing http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git/info/refs
>   fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: do you have any firewalls that may block internet connection?

Comment: You're experiencing this problem due to a GitGub DDoS. They wrote about it in their [blog](https://github.com/blog/1036-about-this-week-s-availability). This is also the reason why several projects are failing on [Travis](http://travis-ci.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using git:// instead of http:// in your deps file

Answer (score 3):

Changing http:// to https:// also works